# lightGallery dynamic mode with subHtmlUrl not working

Tags: gallery, lightgallery

I have try lightGallery dynamic mode with subHtml for caption, and its working fine as below :

## HTML and JavaScript with subHtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>lightGallery demo</title>
        <link href="../dist/css/lightgallery-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">  
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              margin: 0; 
              padding: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="dynamic123">Launch Gallery</button>      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/thumbnail/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/zoom/lg-zoom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/rotate/lg-rotate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/fullscreen/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
        <script>        
            const $dynamicGallery = document.getElementById('dynamic123');
            const dynamicGallery = lightGallery($dynamicGallery, {
                download: false,
                plugins: [lgZoom, lgRotate, lgFullscreen],
                dynamic: true,
                allowMediaOverlap: true,
                dynamicEl: [
                    {
                        src: 'img/2-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-1.jpg',
                        subHtml: '<h3>test 1</h3>',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'img/13-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-13.jpg',
                        subHtml: '<h3>test 2</h3>',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'img/4-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-4.jpg',
                        subHtml: '<h3>test 3</h3>',
                    }
                ],
        });
        $dynamicGallery.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Starts with third item.(Optional).
            // This is useful if you want use dynamic mode with
            // custom thumbnails (thumbnails outside gallery),
            dynamicGallery.openGallery(0);
        });
        </script>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

**Result :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozPTv.png)

but why it's not working if I implement it with **subHtmlUrl **?
With **subHtmlUrl **gallery was appeared but not showing any caption.

I have try below code :

## HTML and JavaScript with subHtmlUrl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>lightGallery demo</title>
        <link href="../dist/css/lightgallery-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">  
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              margin: 0; 
              padding: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="dynamic123">Launch Gallery</button>      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/thumbnail/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/zoom/lg-zoom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/rotate/lg-rotate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/plugins/fullscreen/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
        <script>        
            const $dynamicGallery = document.getElementById('dynamic123');
            const dynamicGallery = lightGallery($dynamicGallery, {
                download: false,
                plugins: [lgZoom, lgRotate, lgFullscreen],
                dynamic: true,
                allowMediaOverlap: true,
                dynamicEl: [
                    {
                        src: 'img/2-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-1.jpg',
                        subHtmlUrl: 'dynamic_caption.php?id=1',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'img/13-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-13.jpg',
                        subHtmlUrl: 'dynamic_caption.php?id=2',
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'img/4-1600.jpg',
                        thumb: 'img/thumb-4.jpg',
                        subHtmlUrl: 'dynamic_caption.php?id=3',
                    }
                ],
        });
        $dynamicGallery.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Starts with third item.(Optional).
            // This is useful if you want use dynamic mode with
            // custom thumbnails (thumbnails outside gallery),
            dynamicGallery.openGallery(0);
        });
        </script>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

## PHP Script : dynamic_caption.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
switch($id){
  case 1:
        echo '<h3>test 1</h3>';
  break;
  case 2:
        echo '<h3>test 2</h3>';
  break;
  case 3:
        echo '<h3>test 3</h3>';
  break;
  default:
    echo '<h3>test 0</h3>';
  break;
}
?>
```

**Result :**
Gallery successfully show up but not showing any caption,
when push next button, XHR request success as below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRI9v.png)

I expecting the caption will showed up as using **subHtml**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thankyou